# I installed dplyr in RStudio, but I can't use it. Can someone take a look my error? Thanks

Tags: r

> install.packages("dplyr")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/I0290048/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/dplyr_0.8.3.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 3266266 bytes (3.1 MB)
>   downloaded 3.1 MB

package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\I0290048\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpslj0Nv\downloaded_packages

> library(dplyr)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
>    unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/XXXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/purrr/libs/x64/purrr.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your installation of the `purrr` package is broken.
* Close R
* delete the `purrr` folder
* open R and install `purrr`